# Submit a form after fields check using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, field

I want to submit a form after the fields' check, but the form doesn't submit even when all the fields are filled. This is the code:

```
$(function(){
$("#submit").click(function() {

    var errors = false;
    if ($("#category").val() === "") {
        $("#category").before('<span>Choisissez une catégorie</span>');
        errors = true;
    }

    if ($("#type").val() === "") {
        $("#type").before('<span>Choisissez Le type</span>');
        errors = true;
    }

    if ($("#designiation").val() === "") {
        $("#designiation").before('<span>Choisissez une désigniation</span>');
        errors = true;
    }

    if (errors == true) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
        $(".add").submit();
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: if (errors == true). You forgot one '='. Check value, do not set it. :)

Comment: thank you i rly didn't notice that :)

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a value before submitting. This code will never run:

```
$(".add").submit();
```

I'm not pretty sure I got you, but if your trying to submit the `.add` form if there are no errors, then swap the `return true` line with the `$(".add").submit();` in the last else block.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your submit code before the return statement. By your way, the submission process will never start. This is what I mean:

```
else {
    $(".add").submit();
    return true;
}
```